# Iptables - удалить\создать правила для ТАБЛИЦЫ

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, firewall

Я знаю, что можно создавать и удалять правила iptables для цепочек. Возможно ли подобное для таблиц? 
И, если нет, возможно ли автоматизировать создание правил без использования скриптов?
Например, эти три правила объединить в одно:

```
iptables -t filter -A INPUT -i ens38 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -i ens38 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i ens38 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Приведите пример того, что вы хотите добавить для таблицы. И еще можете посмотреть на `nftables`.

Comment: Iptables-save iptables-restore рулят если надо вместо скриптов загрузить все правила разом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько мне известно, добавлять правила можно только в цепочки.

Для реализации вашей задачи подходит создание новой цепочки и перенаправление в нее пакетов из `INPUT`, `OUTPUT`, `FORWARD`.

Делается так:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -N my_chain

iptables -A INPUT -j my_chain
iptables -A OUTPUT -j my_chain
iptables -A FORWARD -j my_chain

iptables -A my_chain -i ens38 -j ACCEPT
```

Только такой фильтр - плохая идея. Правила для `INPUT` не имеют полной совместимости с `OUTPUT`, например.

```
iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -i ens38 -j ACCEPT
```

Как вы себе это представляете? Выполнить пробовали?

Comment: На счет совместимости - не заметил. Просто как пример написал. В основном правила будут на протоколы и порты, без интерфейсов.)